# How to convert HSI (a.k.a. HSL) to RGBW+Amber color space

Tags: colors, color-space

I'm writing a driver for RGBWA neo pixels for a hobby project and struggle coming up with a good conversion algorithm from HSI to RGBWA. The primary issue is that one needs to find constraints for the conversion, as the vector space would be over defined. While this is somewhat easy for RGBW and well documented on the internet, it turns out to be not that trivial for adding any supplementary color than white.

I experimented with constraining blue to be zero in case h is in the range 0 to 60 degree but it yield worse results for yellow colors than using only the RGB components of the led. I also asked people working in a theatre (where these lamps are already quite common) and they replied that they choose a color that is a bit off and mix in the amber component by hand until it looks good, which does not sound like a reasonable approach to me.

Does anyone know of a good conversion algorithm that is capable of achieving good results?

Comment: Well, the thing about decorative LED color mixing is that they are all wrong if the input is sRGB -- the primary colors just are not the same and the brightness control is not exactly super stable. It just happens to turn out acceptable because there's no thing to compare a vague shade of light to, unlike with a real OLED display.

Comment: I suppose given a spectrum (SPD) of your RGBWA LED, you can find how much XYZ each light throws out and find, welp, infinite ways to add them up and match the XYZ of the input sRGB color. You first build a new RGB colorspace out of the LED colors, then find out how much of each color the W and A lights are equivalent to (in terms of XYZ) -- negative values are fine, because that's still imaginary stuff. Then you use these equivalents to replace as much W as possible and throw in some A for the guys that stretch out of the RGB gamut.